# Perl code for multiple JSON messages parsing

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to write a perl code to parse multiple JSON messages. The perl code that I have written only parses the values if the JSON file contains only one json message. But it fails when there are multiple messages in that file. It throws error: "Undefined subroutine &Carp::shortmess_heavy". The JSON file is in the following format:

```
    {
    "/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest4" : [],
    "/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest2" : [
     {
     "tag1" : "",
     "tag2" : true,
     "tag3" : [
        {
           "status" : "TRUE",
           "name" : "DEF",
           "age" : "28",
           "sex" : "f"
        },
        {
           "status" : "FALSE",
           "name" : "PQR",
           "age" : "39",
           "sex" : "f"
        }
     ],
     "tag4" : "FAILED",
     "tag5" : "/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest2/test02",
     "tag6" : ""
   }
],
"/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest1" : [
{
     "tag1" : "",
     "tag2" : false,
     "tag3" : [
        {
           "status" : "TRUE",
           "name" : "ABC",
           "age" : "21",
           "sex" : "m"
        },
        {
           "status" : "FALSE",
           "name" : "XYZ",
           "age" : "34",
           "sex" : "f"
        }
     ],
     "tag4" : "PASSED",
     "tag5" : "/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest1/test01",
     "tag6" : ""
   }
   ],
 "/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest6" : []
}
```

My perl code to parse a single JSON message:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;
use JSON qw( decode_json );

my $json_file = "tmp1.json";

my $json;
open (my $fh, '<', $json_file) or die "can not open file $json_file";
{ local $/; $json = <$fh>; }
close($fh);

my $decoded = decode_json($json);

print "TAG4 = " . $decoded->{'tag4'} . "\n";
print "TAg5 = " . $decoded->{'tag5'} . "\n";

my @tag3 = @{ $decoded->{'tag3'} };
foreach my $tg3 ( @tag3 ) {
print "Name = ". $tg3->{"name"} . "\n";
print "Status = ". $tg3->{"status"} . "\n";
print "Age = ". $tg3->{"age"} . "\n";

}
```

Comment: The error message means that you probably miss a dependency. Are you using a system Perl that's installed through a bunch of operating system packages? Your JSON does not have several structures. It looks like it's an object that is missing the outermost curly braces `{}`. Can you fix the input?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have put the external braces.

Comment: You need to upgrade Carp. Try `cpan Carp`.

Comment: My code works if the JSON file, tmp1.json contains the following single message: {  "tag1" : "",
         "tag2" : true,
     "tag3" : [
        {
           "status" : "TRUE",
           "name" : "DEF",
           "age" : "28",
           "sex" : "f"
        },
        {
           "status" : "FALSE",
           "name" : "PQR",
           "age" : "39",
           "sex" : "f"
        }
     ],
     "tag4" : "FAILED",
     "tag5" : "/test/test1/test2/test3/supertest2/test02",
     "tag6" : ""
   }

Comment: So you have a file with more than one structure in that one file, where each of those structures looks like the example in the question? JSON doesn't like that. Please include more of your file. The most relevant part is missing right now.

Comment: That is the complete file with more repeated similar structures within the external curly braces.

Comment: Now your code doesn't match the data structure any more.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the real data that causes the problem, or some similar data that produces the same error.

Answer (score 4):

To parse multiple JSON objects, use JSON::XS/Cpanel::JSON::XS's incremental parsing.

```
my $json = '{"foo":"bar"}   ["baz"]   true   1.23';
   
my @results = JSON::XS->new->allow_nonref->incr_parse($json);
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@results;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'foo' => 'bar'
          },
          [
            'baz'
          ],
          bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
          '1.23'
        ];
```